# DBT - [WARNING]: Did not find matching node for patch

Tags: dbt

I keep getting the error below when I use *dbt run* - I can't find anything on why this error occurs or how to fix it within the dbt documentation.

```
[WARNING]: Did not find matching node for patch with name 'vGenericView' in the 'models' section of file 'models\generic_schema\schema.sql'
```

Answer (score 10):

did you by chance recently upgrade to dbt 1.0.0? If so, this means that you have a model, `vGenericView` defined in a `schema.yml` but you don't have a `vGenericView.sql` model file to which it corresponds.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of this error, you were correct as I misspelt a view name in my schema.yml file.

Comment: It can also happen the other way around, like in my case: I had the corresponding sql file but did not have it in my schema.yml. Adding an entry to schema.yml solved the warning.

Comment: Is there a way to turn this into an error?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292414/dbt-switch-node-path-warnings-to-errors/73295930#73295930

Answer (score 5):

So the mistake is here in the naming:

The model name in the `models.yml` file should for example be: `employees`
And the sql file should be named:  `employees.sql`

So your `models.yml` will look like:

```yaml
version: 2

models:
  - name: employees
    description: "View of employees"
```

And there must be a model with file name: `employees.sql`

Comment: We ran into this recently: the model name is case sensitive!

Comment: We had this error when custom tests written with "{% test" were documented in schema.yml under "macros: " instead of "tests: "

Answer (score 2):

If all views and tables defined in schema are 1 to 1 with model files then try to run `dbt clean` and test or run afterward.

Not sure what happened to my project, but ran into frustration looking for missing and/or misspelled files when it was just leftovers from different compiled files not cleaned out. Previously moved views around to different schemas and renamed others.

Answer (score 0):

One case when this will happen is if you have the same data source defined in two different schema.yml file (or whatever you call it)